# How to clear the screen before suspending Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, sleep, privacy

Before showing the Ubuntu (16.04) login splash screen, my laptop displays the frame which was shown just before closing the lid for about half a second. Then, it refreshes the screen and shows the desktop wallpaper and the login prompt.

I would like my system to show the login screen immediately for privacy reasons. Is there an easy way to enforce this? I was thinking about something like displaying a black frame over the whole screen just before the system goes to sleep. I did not have this issue while using OpenSuse on the same laptop. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up installing [`i3lock`](https://github.com/i3/i3lock), which solved the issue.